# Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Code to kill integrated terminal processes gracefully?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

My Node.js script does some cleanup on exit by catching various signals or the `process.on('exit', ...)` event.

When I run this script in a vscode integrated terminal and close or reload the editor or use the "Kill Terminal" button, well, it kills the terminal and the cleanup portion of the script is not executed.

Current workaround (not ideal): manually send Ctrl+C to terminals.